# Autolayout programmatic aspect ratio setting

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, ios-autolayout

I am trying to add a subview to view and define autolayout constraints, including aspect ratio. But aspect ratio that I see at runtime is not what I defined in constraints. What am I doing wrong? As you can see in code, background view height should be 0.5 of background view width, but that's not the case here in the screenshot. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

private var backgroundView:UIView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
    backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1.0)
    backgroundView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    backgroundView?.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    backgroundView?.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    backgroundView?.clipsToBounds = true
    backgroundView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(backgroundView!)

    backgroundView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    backgroundView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView!.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
    backgroundView?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view!.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    backgroundView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view!.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
}


 }
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Show image of UI for more understanding.

Comment: Why are you setting a frame when you are using autolayout?

Comment: Try- change height constraint to : `.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)`

Comment: @LalKrishna heightAnchor takes an dimension, constant and multiplier as parameter **or** a constant.

Comment: Actually what's problem you are facing? I didn't find any problem after running this code.

Comment: Ok I have edited the question along with screenshot. Why is height of the black view not equal to height of view divided by 2?

Comment: because you are set to its width. `.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView!.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true` change to `.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view!.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true`

Comment: You mean backgroundView.heightAnchor = backgroundView.heightAnchor*0.5? How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Your question have still missing pure information. What you want ??? and What is issue ? Please clear it.

Answer (score 1):

***"background view height should be 0.5 of background view width"***

Your screenshot size is `1334 x 750`

Your `backgroundView` - including the border - is `1334 x 667`

`1334 * 0.5 == 667`

So, you are getting exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change height constraint to set:

```
backgroundView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view!.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
```

**NB:** You are getting the exact result which you are looking for. It has the height that's half of its width. There is nothing wrong with the screenshot.

Comment: Please read the code again, it is set to width anchor, not height anchor. Width anchor has already been set in the previous line of code.

Comment: I saw it. But in comment you asked for `Why is height of the black view not equal to height of view divided by 2?` So that you need view that height should be half of its `self.view`'s height., isn't it? Is this your requirement?

Comment: My requirement is what is wrong with the code? Why are the two lines not setting aspect ratio.

Comment: You are setting the backgroundView's height as `backgroundView.width / 2.0`

Comment: And why is that not happening in the screenshot?

Comment: That's what the screenshot shows. It has the height that's half of its width. What's the wrong with the screenshot?

Comment: Oops, there is a mistake. It should be 9.0/16.0 as iPhone 6s screen aspect ratio. Thanks!

Comment: Because you misquoted the code. But I will take it back as soon as you edit the answer.

Comment: Please update the question with you final screen you are trying to achieve. So that we can help. I didn't understand how iphone 6 ratio related to this question.